# Access Angular service when manually bootstrapping / initializing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to access to a method of a factory service, *before* Angular has been bootstrapped, similar to the code below?

I need to make a number of AJAX requests before Angular starts in order to set a number of global application variables. I had hoped to keep the logic for this and/or store the responses inside an Angular service, and return a promise...

```
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/factories/app.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {

        factoryName.startup().then(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(error fetching bootstrap data);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Is there an alternative method to use to get a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the first service calls in [module run blocks](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). When a later service call is made for those variables, you can either serve them out of $http's cache or have explicitly cached the promise from the first call.

```
// example
myApp.run(function(MyService) {
  // call your function when Angular starts up
  MyService.init();
});
```

Comment: Actually config block you can only inject providers. Everything else will not get injected and hence a http call cannot be made. The run method would be the right place to do anything.

Comment: Gah, was reading up about both and got my wires crossed. Fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example that loads a configuration file before bootstrapping the application.

The first call to bootstrap is done to gain access to angular services like $http and $location (you could also inject your own module at this point to access custom services).

After the configuration file has been loaded, angular.bootstrap is called for the main application, with the loaded configuration set as a constant on a makeshift module(rsacAppBootstrap) that is injected.

Here are at least two advantages over using a promise set from a run block:

1. Reduced boilerplate of promise for everything dependent on configuration
2. Ability to conditionally load dependencies based on the environment using RequireJS

Custom bootstrap script:

```
angular.bootstrap().invoke(function ($http, $location) {

  var env = $location.search()._env || null;
  if (env === true) {
    env = null;
  }

  var configUri = 'config/env.json';
  if (env) {
    configUri = configUri.replace('json', env + '.json');
  }

  var rsacAppBootstrap = angular.module('rsacAppBootstrap', [])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $window) {
      var env = $location.search()._env;
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
        var newEnv = $location.search()._env;
        if (env !== newEnv) {
          $window.location.reload();
        }
      })
    });

  function bootstrap(config) {
    rsacAppBootstrap.constant('rsacConfig', config || {});
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      var modules = ['rsacApp', 'rsacAppBootstrap'];
      if (config.modules){
        config.modules.forEach(function(v){
          modules.push(v);
        })
      }
      angular.bootstrap(document, modules);
    });
  }

  $http.get(configUri)
    .success(function (config) {
      config._env = env;
      if (config.require) {
        require(config.require, function(){
          bootstrap(config);
        });
      } else {
        bootstrap(config);
      }
    })
    .error(function () {
      bootstrap();
    });

});
```

Example configuration file:

```
{
  "_meta": [
    "Development environment settings"
  ],

  "require":[
    "//code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-mocks.js",
    "components/rsacMock/js/rsacMock.js"
  ],

  "modules":[
    "ngMockE2E",
    "rsacMock"
  ],

  "resources": { ... }

}
```