# Calling service method before manually bootstrapping Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read through [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909009/access-angular-service-when-manually-bootstrapping-initializing) but don't believe that it is the solution to my problem.

I have an app in which I require the currently logged-in user's details before loading up the app. This appears to be very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339582/angularjs-manually-bootstrap-after-receive-data) but the difference is that I want to use a method that already exists in my `authenticationService` before bootstrapping the app, and cache the result in that service.

**app.bootstrap.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    fetchUser()
        .then(bootstrapApplication);

    function fetchUser() {
        var injector = angular.injector(['app']);
        var authenticationService = injector.get('authenticationService');

        return authenticationService.getUser().then(function(response) {
          // Got user successfully, user is now cached in authenticationService.user
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    }

    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
      });
    }

})();
```

I can call that service method fine, but the problem comes when I bootstrap the app and a new instance of that service is created and, as a result, the data I cached from the HTTP request is in a different instance of the service.

**authentication.service.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.authentication')
        .factory('authenticationService', authenticationService);

    authenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies', '$log', '$q', 'API_SETTINGS', '_'];

    function authenticationService($http, $cookies, $log, $q, API_SETTINGS, _) {
        var factory = {
            user          : {},
            login         : login,
            logout        : logout,
            getUser       : getUser,
            isLoggedIn    : isLoggedIn,
            getSessionId  : getSessionId
        };

        return factory;

        function getUser() {
            return $http.get(API_SETTINGS.url + '/account', { 
                params: { 
                    'api_key'     : API_SETTINGS.key,
                    'session_id'  : $cookies.get('sessionId')
                }})
            .then(function(response) {
                // Great, cache the user and return the response
                factory.user = response.data;
                return response;
            });
        }

    }

})();
```

Is there anyway I can use the same instance of my `authenticationService` to make the HTTP call before bootstrapping and after? Or is there an alternative?

One thing I have considered is attaching the user to the `window` in the `fetchUser` success callback so that in my `authenticationService` I can set `factory.user = $window.user || {}`, but i'd prefer not to do it this way.

Comment: What we have done in few projects is to let the application bootstrap, but actually [defer router component initialization](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) until user and his configuration is loaded.

Comment: You can define and HTTP interceptor for certain routes, and look for an `authenticated` flag, and if that is not present, you can go ahead and take the user through the login process. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this from the other way around - let your Angular application bootstrap and just prevent your UI to do anything until the security service is initialized.

```
//~ ...

/**
 * Make UI Router wait.
 */
config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
}).

/**
 * Initialize security and then activate UI Router.
 */
run(function($urlRouter, securityManager) {
    securityManager.init().then(function() {
        $urlRouter.sync();
        $urlRouter.listen();
    });
}).

//~ ...
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted - I had been looking for a way to `resolve` the entire router, like you would a single route but couldn't find anything. Thanks.