# Angular2: router highjacking

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Imagine we have a view protected by some sort of external login. Here's the workflow

1. The user tries to access the page.
2. The user is redirected to the external login.
3. The user performs the login.
4. The user is redirected to the protected page.

The first thing I tried was to setup a hook with `routerOnActivate` to check for the authentication and to redirect the user to a login view that performs the redirect. This login view is also the view where the user ends up after the login, so I need to make another redirect to the protected page.

1. routerOnActivate HomeComponent -> navigate(["Login"])
2. routerOnActivate LoginComponent -> window.location.href = redirectUri
3. ...
4. routerOnActivate LoginComponent -> setup auth; navigate(["Home"])

However in certain cases there was a race condition, where at step 2 or 4 the navigation still wasn't complete when it tried to navigate again, and it ended up with an error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewManager' of   nullBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23525ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1145(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:1444(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:5751run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
angular2.dev.js:23514 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23514ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1147(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:14801NgZone._notifyOnError @ angular2.dev.js:5796collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @ angular2.dev.js:5700run @ angular2-polyfills.js:141(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch @ angular2-polyfills.js:1511lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback @ angular2-polyfills.js:1523lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish @ angular2-polyfills.js:1494lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publishRejection @ angular2-polyfills.js:1444(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:243microtask @ angular2.dev.js:5751run @ angular2-polyfills.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:5719zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:111lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush @ angular2-polyfills.js:1305
angular2.dev.js:23514 TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewManager' of null
    at ElementInjector.getViewContainerRef (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12945:78)
    at AppViewManager_.getViewContainer (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11237:68)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:14555:48
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:5719:32)
    at zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)
    at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1494:11)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:243:5
```

said error was a pain in the ass to reproduce and debug, but in the end I discovered it was for this race condition.

So, the question is... How can I do it with the certainty to trigger a navigate only after all the navigation has finished? Should I instead use the `routerCanActivate` hook?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Angular2 (nor its router). But in Angular and UI Router we have implemented login in a way that we disabled activation of the router and did it manually after we knew whether the user is logged or not (in our case OAuth based login involved also few REST calls). So I would probably try to achieve something similar in Angular2 (disable router, let security bootstrap/initialize with a promise and then initialize the router)...

Comment: How did you deal with views that could be accessed anonymously?

Comment: The important thing was really just to let security initialize before router. Then we have hook in the router which just checkes if the route requires authentication. No special treatment for anonymous users... Security components were able to recognize if the URL contains access token or if there is a valid token inside sessionStorage. If not, the access is anonymous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973063/calling-service-method-before-manually-bootstrapping-angular-app/32973442#32973442

Comment: Probably you're looking for [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-var.html) annotation, which [doesn't support DI](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112) but it has a [workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572)